# How to update or insert on Sequel dataset?

Tags: ruby, upsert, sequel

I just started using Sequel in a really small Sinatra app. Since I've got only one DB table, I don't need to use models.

I want to update a record if it exists or insert a new record if it does not. I came up with the following solution:

```
  rec = $nums.where(:number => n, :type => t)
  if $nums.select(1).where(rec.exists)
    rec.update(:counter => :counter + 1)
  else
    $nums.insert(:number => n, :counter => 1, :type => t)
  end
```

Where `$nums` is `DB[:numbers]` dataset.

I believe that this way isn't the most elegant implementation of "update or insert" behavior.

How should it be done?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3647454/increment-counter-or-insert-row-in-one-statement-in-sqlite

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You should probably not check before updating/inserting; because:

1. This is an extra db call.
2. This could introduce a race condition.

What you should do instead is to test the return value of update:

```
rec = $nums.where(:number => n, :type => t)
if 1 != rec.update(:counter => :counter + 1)
  $nums.insert(:number => n, :counter => 1, :type => t)
end
```

Comment: This solution still introduces race condition possibility. If two parallel processes/threads perform update (line 2) before one of them reaches insert (line 3), two records will be inserted. Consider using something like mutex, db lock or appropriate transaction strategy.

Comment: Flexoid: you are right, and the below solution - basically "put everything into a transaction" is correct. Still, there is no point in a "SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT" order of commands when "UPDATE + INSERT" is sufficient. (+ the transaction, of course.) Interesting thing w/transaction: if two transactions running in parallel increment the same counter you *still* run into problems.

Answer (score 17):

Sequel 4.25.0 (released July 31st, 2015) added [`insert_conflict` for Postgres v9.5+](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc-adapters/classes/Sequel/Postgres/DatasetMethods.html#method-i-insert_conflict)
Sequel 4.30.0 (released January 4th, 2016) added [`insert_conflict` for SQLite](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc-adapters/classes/Sequel/SQLite/DatasetMethods.html#method-i-insert_conflict)

This can be used to either insert or update a row, like so:

```
DB[:table_name].insert_conflict(:update).insert( number:n, type:t, counter:c )
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe you can't have it much cleaner than that (although some databases have specific upsert syntax, which might be [supported by Sequel](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/rdoc-adapters/classes/Sequel/MySQL/DatasetMethods.html#method-i-replace_sql)). You can just wrap what you have in a separate method and pretend that it doesn't exist. :)

Just couple suggestions:

- Enclose everything within a transaction.
- Create unique index on `(number, type)` fields.
- Don't use global variables.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [upsert](https://github.com/seamusabshere/upsert), except it doesn't currently work for updating counters. Hopefully a future version will - ideas welcome!